# Forever monitor and sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, forever

My node app is returning

```
Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
```

My app has the following structure:

```
.controllers/
|--getter.js
|--setter.js
.system.js
.slave.js
```

System.js

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');
var path = require('path');
var relativeDir = path.dirname(module.filename);

var childWorker = new(forever.Monitor)(path.join(relativeDir,'slave.js'), {
  max: 3,
  silent: true,
  options: []
});
```

slave.js

```
...
var getter = require('./controllers/getter.js');
var setter = require('./controllers/setter.js');
...
```

getter.js/setter.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var dbPath = '/ABSOLUTEPATH/db';
if (fs.existsSync(dbPath)) {
  console.log("[Getter] DB file found");
  var db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY);
}
else {
  console.log("[Getter] Cannot find DB file");
}
```

I've tried changing from absolute paths to relative paths and changing the owners of the database without any luck. The app is able to find the database file but, for some reason can't open it.

After that I made a simple script "test.js" and placed it in the same dir that "system.js".
I ran it, it worked without errors and returned the right values.

```
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");
var dbPath = "/ABSOLUTEPATH/db";
var db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY);

var sqlQuery = 'SELECT lat, long FROM kkk';
db.get(sqlQuery, function(err, row) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('err!');
    } else {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this command " sudo chown www-data. . " in db file directory.

other solution check the file exists or not ?

ex :

var fs = require("fs");

var exists = fs.existsSync(dbfilepath);